# Need help in R for coding equations

Tags: r, plot, equations

I'm pretty new to using R and I am certainly unsure on how to plug in and graph equations. For an example I have to plot the Goldmann-Hodgkin-Katz equation 
(since my reputation is too low I can't send a nice equation so here's a link)
http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~bard/passive2/node3.html

This is for a neuroscience class and I'm pretty savvy with coding in java but struggle with terminal based languages.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I suggest attempting to solve the problem yourself.  If you struggle, come back and show us what you tried and why it is different than what you wanted. Don't forget to include a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000)  (Also, you didn't actually ask a question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, check out http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/curve.html.

Here is an example:

```
curve(3*x^2 + 2)
```